# How to set WidthRequest=50 to button in Xamarin.Forms for Windows Phone?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.winphone

WidthRequest=50 in Windows phone project not working. In android and iOS it is working. But in WinPhone displaying only half button. I tried with MinimumWidthRequest also, that also not working.

Button takes MinimumWidth of only 109 in windows phone. Less than 109 WIdthRequest, disappears overflowed width.
Does anybody knows how to modify this MinimumWidthRequest in WinPhone? or Any other solution for this?

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <Label Text="WidthRequest=109" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="109" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="109"/>
    <Label Text="WidthRequest=108"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="108" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="108"/>
    <Label Text="WidthRequest=70"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="70" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="70"/>
    <Label Text="WidthRequest=50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    <Button HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Text="50" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"/>
</StackLayout>
```

[This is how Button displays in Windows Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7cps.png)

[This is how Button displays in Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVHAO.png)

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about including a [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally solved the problem, Created `CustomRender` of Button and defined `Control.MinWidth` for Button. `MinimumWidthRequest` not working as expected in Xamarin.Forms.